# Looping VBA within selected range

Tags: vba, loops, range

I am unable to stop my VBA from looping within the range that I have specified, could someone please check my code and tell me where I am going wrong with it.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Macro()

Dim oWs As Worksheet
Dim rSearchRng As Range
Dim lEndNum As Long
Dim vFindVar As Variant
Dim loc As Range
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LRow As Long
Dim Copy As Range

Set oWs = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
LastRow = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row

lEndNum = oWs.Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row
Set Copy = oWs.Range("A2" & LRow)
Set rSearchRng = oWs.Range("A2:A" & CStr(lEndNum))

Set loc = rSearchRng.Cells.Find(Range("O2").Value)

If Not loc Is Nothing Then
 Do Until loc Is Nothing
 loc.Select
 Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0), ActiveCell.Offset(0, 12)).Select
 Selection.Copy
 Sheets("Sheet2").Select
 LastRow = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
 Range("A" & LastRow).Select
 Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths, Operation:=xlNone, _
 SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
 ActiveSheet.Paste
 Sheets("Sheet1").Select
 Application.CutCopyMode = False
 Set loc = rSearchRng.FindNext(loc)
 Loop
End If

Set loc = Nothing


MsgBox "Complete"
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance

Aydos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's because Find() method keeps on going inside the range
so you have to stop it when it wraps back to the first found cell by monitoring its address, as follows (along with some other refactoring):

```
Sub Macro()

    Dim oWs As Worksheet
    Dim rSearchRng As Range
    Dim lEndNum As Long
    Dim vFindVar As Variant
    Dim loc As Range
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim LRow As Long
    Dim Copy As Range

    Set oWs = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    LastRow = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row

    lEndNum = oWs.Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row
    Set Copy = oWs.Range("A2" & LRow)
    Set rSearchRng = oWs.Range("A2:A" & CStr(lEndNum))

    Dim locFirstAddress As String

    Set loc = rSearchRng.Cells.Find(Range("O2").value)

    If Not loc Is Nothing Then
        locFirstAddress = loc.Address
        Do
            Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0), ActiveCell.Offset(0, 12)).Copy
            With Sheets("Sheet2")
                .Range("A" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
                .Paste
            End With
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            Set loc = rSearchRng.FindNext(loc)
        Loop While loc.Address <> locFirstAddress
    End If

    Set loc = Nothing


    MsgBox "Complete"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quote from the help text on FindNext

> When the search reaches the end of the specified search range, it wraps around to the beginning of the range. To stop a search when this wraparound occurs, save the address of the first found cell, and then test each successive found-cell address against this saved address.

I think that applies to your situation